# htaccess - load files on fake path

Tags: .htaccess

I have the following code on my .htaccess file:

```
RewriteRule    ^([0-9A-Za-z]{12})(\/.+|\.html?|$)  /stuff/index.cgi?etc=dostuff [L]
```

with this rule people can access urls like:

```
http://domain.com/by6xq1ybc7zz/something.html
```

I want to include css, js, php on fake path /by6xq1ybc7zz

right now I have to load my files from the parent directory. I want to load the files from the current directory.

**right now I have to load files from parent directory:**

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="../script.js"></script>
```

**But I want to load files on the current directory:**

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="script.js"></script>
```

So how I can include files in this **fake** directory?

```
http://domain.com/by6xq1ybc7zz/[STORE MY FILES ON THIS FAKE DIRECTORY]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Enable `mod_rewrite` and `.htaccess` through `httpd.conf` and then put this code in your `.htaccess` under **`DOCUMENT_ROOT` directory**:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
# Turn mod_rewrite on
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteRule ^[0-9A-Za-z]{12}/([^.]+\.(?:js|css|php))$ /$1 [L,NC]

# your existing rule
RewriteRule ^([0-9A-Za-z]{12})(/.+|\.html?|$) /stuff/index.cgi?etc=dostuff [L]
```

Comment: you are amazing, worked well. after 1 week searching on google and coding forums. you solved my problem in just 2 minutes. thanks again!